# [u'\r\n ', u'\r\n Block-B, Faisal Town', u'\r\n Fax: (042) 516 5232\r\n ']

Tags: python, string, list

```
location = str(response.xpath('//*[@id="addresses"]/address[2]/text()').extract()).strip("1234567890=,/\n\ru")
```

I want to remove the spaces and garbage like \n , \r , u etc from the list in python.

I have tried to use the `strip` function but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (to map, filter list items) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (to remove spaces around the strings, including `\r`, `\n`):

```
>>> result = [u'\r\n ', u'\r\n Block-B, Faisal Town', u'\r\n Fax: (042) 516 5232\r\n ']
>>> result = [x.strip() for x in result]
>>> result = [x for x in result if x]
>>> result
[u'Block-B, Faisal Town', u'Fax: (042) 516 5232']
```